# How to get 'fileId' for Google Drive files?

Tags: python, google-drive-api

I have a web-app which allows users to create and edit Google Drive files. I am able to create and save new files. But when I want to update an existing file I can't do that. According to Google Drive API reference to update an existing file user needs to provide 'fileId' for that file. But how do I get the fileId for a particular file? I have the file title with me, but how can get 'fileId'?

I am using following code to do that:

```
fileId = <How to get this?>
media_body = MediaFileUpload(filename, mimetype='text/x-script.phyton', resumable=True)
body = {
    'title': filename,
    'description': 'File saved from Pythonista app',
    'mimeType': 'text/x-script.phyton'
}
existing_file = service.files().get().execute()
if existing_file:
    resource = service.files().update(
        fileId=fileId,
        body=existing_file,
        newRevision=True,
        media_body=media_body).execute()
```

Answer (score 1):

You always need to keep that id when you're getting the files. Unlike Dropbox, path and file name for GD gives you almost nothing.

Please refer to this resources:

When you getting list of user items you're making query similar to this [Link: Google Drive SDK API for files listing](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/list)

Inside of the "files" container expect to find such data:

```
{
  "kind": "drive#file",
  "id": string,  <<<<< HERE
  "etag": etag,
    ****
  "title": string, <<<<<<< Name of the file you already use
    ****
  }
}
```

[Link: Google Drive SDK API for file resource info](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files#resource)

So in your code you should pass ID most of the time, file name is not crucial here.